# CreateWindow argument type error

Tags: c++, directx, hwnd

I am just starting to play around with C++ and creating windows(On windows). I am using the `CreateWindow` function and I am getting the error

```
Error   2   error C2664: 'HWND CreateWindowExA(DWORD,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,int,int,int,int,HWND,HMENU,HINSTANCE,LPVOID)' : cannot convert argument 9 from 'const int' to 'HWND'
```

and here is the code in question

```
//Create the window
hwnd = CreateWindow(
    "HelloDirectXClass",//Class name, defined above
    "Hello DirectX",//Top bar title
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU, WS_CAPTION,//Window style, using default
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - WIDTH / 2,//Position relitive to top left corner, X CXSCREEN notice the CX<--for X or width
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - HEIGHT / 2,//Position relitive to top left corner, Y CYSCREEN notice the CY<--for Y or height
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    (HWND)NULL,//Setting window parent
    (HMENU)NULL,
    hInstance,//Window instance defined above
    (LPVOID)NULL);
```

By looking at the error I would asume that it is trying to say that it couldn't convert arg 9, `(HMENU)NULL`,  in the function from an integer to a `HWND` type. This does not make any sence because the docs say arg 9 should be a `HMENU` like I have.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/WAZHEDu4) is a full code dump

Comment: The error message refers to CreateWindowExA not CreateWindow

Comment: @VladfromMoscow which confused me even more because I don't use `CreateWindowExA` if you look at my full code dump.

Comment: CreateWindow is just a macro definition, and if you are under non UNICODE compilation then it resolves to CreateWindowExA

Comment: @marcin_j how would I fix this?

Comment: This is just a typo, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your bug

`WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU, WS_CAPTION,`

Replace this character: `,` before `WS_CAPTION` with `|`